# Gradle nested projects setup

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

How do I set up such a project structure where I have the root project called "app", "frontend" and "backend" project inside and a count of library projects inside each. Then run a build task that would give me one backend jar and a swing (for example) jar application.

Like this:

- root (App)
- - frontend
- - - library
- - - main
- - backend
- - - library
- - - main

then run: `gradle build` and have `build/.../frontend.jar` and `build/.../backend.jar`

I did try using `include` inside `settings.gradle` but that doesn't seem to work (at least `gradle projects` and intellij idea do not recognise the projects inside `frontend` and `backend`). I had:

`root/settings.gradle` with: `include 'frontend', 'backend'`
`root/backend/settings.gradle` with: `include 'library', 'main'`
and the same for `frontend`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern Gradle it's possible to `includeBuild`, which solves the problem perfeclty:

```kotlin
// root/settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "root"

includeBuild("backend")
includeBuild("frontend")
```

```kotlin
// root/backend/settings.gradle.kts and root/frontend/settings.gradle.kts

include(":library")
include(":main")
```

Comment: Say root(App) had another common module within it (at the same level as 'frontend'/'backend') - would it be possible to add it as a dependency within 'frontend' or 'backend'?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. one way at the root settings.gradle (gradle v7.1)

```
rootProject.name = 'test-prj-tree'
include 'backend'
include 'frontend'
include 'library'
include 'backend:library'
findProject(':backend:library')?.name = 'backend-lib'
include 'backend:main'
findProject(':backend:main')?.name = 'backend-main'
include 'frontend:library'
findProject(':frontend:library')?.name = 'frontend-lib'
include 'frontend:main'
findProject(':frontend:main')?.name = 'frontend-main'
```